# Cannot insert into mongo db with python

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mlab

I am hosting a mongo database on [mlab](https://mlab.com), and I have an extremely simple program to insert a document into an existing collection. Insertion works for me in JS but not in Python for some reason. This is what it looks like in Python:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://<user>:<password>@<address>/<db-name>') 
db = client.congresspersons
posts = db.posts
post_data = {
    'title': 'Python and MongoDB',
    'content': 'PyMongo is fun, you guys',
    'author': 'Scott'
}
result = posts.insert_one(post_data)
```

This code mostly came from [here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-mongodb-and-python/#mongodb).

However, I keep getting this error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not authorized on config to execute command { insert: "congresspersons.posts", ordered: true, documents: [ { content: "PyMongo is fun, you guys", _id: ObjectId('5ab16ae3626b6217f7c2a079'), author: "Scott", title: "Python and MongoDB" } ] }
```

These are the permissions for the user:

```
{
    ...
    "roles": [
        {
            "role": "dbOwner",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't understand why such simple insertion is not working in Python. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Problem  `db = client.congresspersons`, You can try this code

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://<user>:<password>@<address>')
db = client['<db-name>']
posts = db['posts_name']
post_data = {
    'title': 'Python and MongoDB',
    'content': 'PyMongo is fun, you guys',
    'author': 'Scott'
}
result = posts.insert_one(post_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although tuan huynh's answer didn't exactly solve my problem, I played around with it and it helped me reach the solution:

from pymongo import MongoClient

The URI stays the same as before, I just say

```
db = client.<db-name>
posts = db.<collection-name>
```